# Use WHERE clause along with Between and NULL parameter for 2 date fields

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008

Working with Parameters and SQL in a SSRS report

@FromDate and @ToDate can be null              -- To get all 4 records

@Fromdate can have a date value while @ToDate is null - if this is the case need to get all date value which does not have TravelTo Date

@Fromdate and @todate has values then need to get the last 2  records

@FromDate and @ToDate is null then need to get all value

I used the  below code to get the data but i am not getting the right data ,any suggestion is appreciated.

Where
(TravelTo BETWEEN @FROMSTART AND @TODATE)

or(@TODATE IS NULL and TravelFrom >=@FROMSTART )

OR(@FROMSTART IS NULL AND TravelFrom <=@TODATE)

OR(@FROMSTART IS NULL AND @TODATE IS NULL)

[image]

Parmater screenshot from SSRS

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the either the date inputs or the columns themselves could be `NULL`, you may try:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    (@FROMSTART > TravelFrom OR @FROMSTART IS NULL OR TravelFrom IS NULL) AND
    (@TODATE < TravelTo OR @TODATE IS NULL OR TravelTo IS NULL);
```

This logic would discount either the start or end of the date range should either the column have a `NULL` value, or the input have a `NULL` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ((@FROMSTART IS NULL AND @TODATE IS NULL)
OR(@FROMSTART IS NULL AND TravelTo <=@TODATE)
OR(@TODATE IS NULL AND TravelFrom >=@FROMSTART)
OR(TravelFrom >= @FROMSTART AND TravelTo<=@TODATE))
```

Hope this Query Works fine for your case:

You had forgot to mentioned these conditions within an Open/Close bracket.So that only you cannot get the right output.

Comment: Share your comments if you have any queries - @user5368688

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the 2nd condition

> @Fromdate can have a date value while @ToDate is null - if this is the case need to get all date value which does not have TravelTo Date

Please try the code below which does (I think) what you specified in your question. If this does not work, please supply a set of test dates and expected outcome for each test as some are a little ambiguous.

**NOTE:** I have used standard date format for the dates as these will not suffer from conversion to and from the MM/DD/YYYY format you are using.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID int, TravelFrom date, TravelTo date)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(9759497, '2020-02-01', NULL),
(5226416, '2020-01-15', NULL),
(2731975, '2020-03-01', '2020-04-30'),
(2318260, '2020-01-01', '2020-02-28')


DECLARE @fromDate date = '2020-02-01'
DECLARE @toDate date = NULL


SELECT *  FROM @t
    WHERE 
    (TravelFrom >= @fromDate or @fromDate is null)
    AND
    (TravelTo <= @toDate or @toDate is null)
    AND
    (
        CASE WHEN @toDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
        =
        CASE WHEN TravelTo IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     )
```

Comment: This worked and i am able to get data for the  4 criteria i was looking  for